# Compiz gone after 12.04 updates

Tags: 12.04, compiz

I am using 12.04 LTS here at work and since the last update cycle, Compiz is completely not running anymore. I use the "hot corner" a lot, as well as configured 4x2 virtual desktops (only have 2x2 now).

I haven't done any changes, only run the updates.

How can I get compiz running again as my default WM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Apparently, Ubuntu does not ship the latest version of the Catalyst AMD driver (I have a Radeon) and because the shipped driver stopped supporting my card, it fell back to a standard driver.

All I had to do was install the latest AMD drivers and reconfig Compiz again.